# Plugin init check if current page is dashboard

Tags: plugin-development

Is there an easy way to check if the current page is the Dashboard?
I have a widget that needs several Javascript resources but if I include them in the widget library I get a google maps error that I should not do that.
`You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

I could make a workaround and set a static public variable to false after the first include but that would be kinda dirty.

So all I want to know id there is something like

```
function init()
{
    if (craft()->isDashBoard()) {
        //include all JS ressources
    }
}
```

or if there is a better way to include Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, but you can use the [`{% includeJsFile %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) tag to include the file(s) from your widget template. In whatever template you render in your widget's `getBodyHtml()` method, add this:

```
{% includeJsFile "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" %}
```

If you need to queue up several files, you'll need several `{% includeJsFile %}` tags. There's also a `{% includeCssFile %}`, if you need to add some external CSS, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You know that init() would fire everytime an action is done, so you would load multiple google map apis it is mostly used for hooking into Events.

I would try something else to load it in.

Control Panel JS plugin for craft and then by there load in your javascript. <- works good if i remember correctly